# useNavigate function not working in React

Tags: javascript

[Room availability](https://i.stack.imgur.com/scw0K.png)

I wanted to show room availability using react, if user click on button, it should redirect to another page with its value. I use useNavigate() to navigate. In console this error is showing. I am using react-router-dom version v6.3.0

```
The above error occurred in the <Rooms> component:

    at Rooms (http://localhost:3000/ReactApp/static/js/bundle.js:34:70)
    at div

Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
Visit https://reactjs.org/link/error-boundaries to learn more about error boundaries.
logCapturedError @ react-dom.development.js:18687
update.callback @ react-dom.development.js:18720
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:13923
commitUpdateQueue @ react-dom.development.js:13944
commitLayoutEffectOnFiber @ react-dom.development.js:23391
commitLayoutMountEffects_complete @ react-dom.development.js:24688
commitLayoutEffects_begin @ react-dom.development.js:24674
commitLayoutEffects @ react-dom.development.js:24612
commitRootImpl @ react-dom.development.js:26823
commitRoot @ react-dom.development.js:26682
finishConcurrentRender @ react-dom.development.js:25892
performConcurrentWorkOnRoot @ react-dom.development.js:25809
workLoop @ scheduler.development.js:266
flushWork @ scheduler.development.js:239
performWorkUntilDeadline @ scheduler.development.js:533
Rooms.js:6 Uncaught TypeError: (0 , react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.useNavigate) is not a function
    at Rooms (Rooms.js:6:1)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:16305:1)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js:20074:1)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:21587:1)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:27426:1)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:26557:1)
    at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:26466:1)
    at renderRootSync (react-dom.development.js:26434:1)
    at recoverFromConcurrentError (react-dom.development.js:25850:1)
    at performConcurrentWorkOnRoot (react-dom.development.js:25750:1)
```

**index.js**

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import Rooms from "./Rooms";

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <div>
  <Rooms />
  </div>
);
```

**room.js** Is  write in return()?

```
import React, { BrowserRouter, Route, Routes, useState, useNavigate } from "react";
import "./index.css"
import Selection from "./new";

export default function Rooms() {
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const newPage = () => {
    navigate("/new");
  };
  
  const numbers = [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0];

  const listItems = numbers.map((numbers,index) =>
  <div>
    <button
    className={numbers ? "green" : "red"}
    disabled={!numbers}
    key={index}
    onClick={newPage}
    >Room no. {(index+1)}
    <br/>{numbers ? " Available" : " Not Available"} </button>
  </div>
  );

  return (
    <>
      <style>{`
        .red {color: red; background-color: silver; margin : 15px; font-size:30px}
        .green {color: green; background-color: white; margin : 15px; font-size:30px}
      `}</style>
      {listItems}

    <BrowserRouter>
    <Routes>
    <Route path ="/new" element={<Selection value={numbers}/>} />
    </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
    </>
  );
}
```

**new.js** Page to navigate

```
export default function Selection(props){
    return(
        <h1>{props.value} No. Selected </h1>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As i can see in your import, You have imported useNavigate from 'react' which is wrong package. Please import from 'react-router-dom';.